# Querying COUNT(*) over many tables takes more than half a second per row

Tags: mysql

I have the following database structure:

projects

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Test |
| 2 | Test 2 |

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects`
(
    `id`                  bigint unsigned                         NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name`                varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci              DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 5772
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

participant_subscriptions

| id | project_id | alternative_project_id | deleted_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null | null |
| 2 | null | 2 | null |
| 3 | null | null | null |

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `participant_subscriptions`
(
    `id`                      bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `project_id`              bigint unsigned      DEFAULT NULL,
    `alternative_project_id`  bigint unsigned      DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted_at`              timestamp       NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `participant_subscriptions_project_id_foreign` (`project_id`),
    KEY `participant_subscriptions_alternative_project_id_foreign` (`alternative_project_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `participant_subscriptions_alternative_project_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`alternative_project_id`) REFERENCES `projects` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `participant_subscriptions_project_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `projects` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 15050
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

participant_subscription_project

| id | participant_subscription_id | project_id | alternative_project_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | null |

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `participant_subscription_project`
(
    `id`                          bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `participant_subscription_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
    `project_id`                  bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
    `alternative_project_id`      bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `participant_subscription_project_unique` (`participant_subscription_id`, `project_id`),
    KEY `participant_subscription_project_project_id_foreign` (`project_id`),
    KEY `participant_subscription_project_alternative_project_id_foreign` (`alternative_project_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `participant_subscription_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`participant_subscription_id`) REFERENCES `participant_subscriptions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT `participant_subscription_project_alternative_project_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`alternative_project_id`) REFERENCES `projects` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `participant_subscription_project_project_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `projects` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 4066
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_c
```

subscription_details

| id | option | confirmed | participant_subscription_id | participant_subscription_project_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null | 1 | null |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | null |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | null | 3 |

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subscription_details`
(
    `id`                                  bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `option`                              tinyint(1)                              DEFAULT '0',
    `confirmed`                           tinyint(1)                              DEFAULT '0', 
    `participant_subscription_id`         bigint unsigned                         DEFAULT NULL,
    `participant_subscription_project_id` bigint unsigned                         DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `subscription_details_participant_subscription_id_unique` (`participant_subscription_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `subscription_details_participant_subscription_project_id_unique` (`participant_subscription_project_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `subscription_details_participant_subscription_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`participant_subscription_id`) REFERENCES `participant_subscriptions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT `subscription_details_participant_subscription_project_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`participant_subscription_project_id`) REFERENCES `participant_subscription_project` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 28198
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And I would like to know the total amount of subscriptions of a single project. So made the following sub-query:

```sql
SELECT `projects`.*,
(
            (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `participant_subscriptions`
                LEFT JOIN `subscription_details` ON (
                    `subscription_details`.`participant_subscription_id` = `participant_subscriptions`.`id`
                    AND`subscription_details`.`option` = 1 AND `subscription_details`.`confirmed` = 1
                )
                WHERE `projects`.`id` = `participant_subscriptions`.`project_id` AND
                    `participant_subscriptions`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND
                    # Exclude optional
                    `subscription_details`.`id` IS NULL
            ) +
            (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `participant_subscriptions`
                LEFT JOIN `subscription_details` ON (
                    `subscription_details`.`participant_subscription_id` = `participant_subscriptions`.`id`
                    AND `subscription_details`.`option` = 1 AND `subscription_details`.`confirmed` = 1
                )
                WHERE `projects`.`id` = `participant_subscriptions`.`alternative_project_id` AND
                    `participant_subscriptions`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND
                    # Exclude optional
                    `subscription_details`.`id` IS NULL
            ) +
            (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `participant_subscription_project`
                JOIN `participant_subscriptions` ON `participant_subscriptions`.`id` = `participant_subscription_project`.`participant_subscription_id`
                WHERE `projects`.`id` = `participant_subscription_project`.`project_id` AND
                    `participant_subscriptions`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
            ) +
            (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `participant_subscription_project`
                JOIN `participant_subscriptions` ON `participant_subscriptions`.`id` = `participant_subscription_project`.`participant_subscription_id`
                WHERE `projects`.`id` = `participant_subscription_project`.`alternative_project_id` AND
                    `participant_subscriptions`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
            )
        ) AS `participants_count`
FROM `projects` WHERE `projects`.`id` = 1
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | projects | NULL | const | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | const | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | participant_subscription_project | NULL | ref | participant_subscription_project_unique,participan... | participant_subscription_project_alternative_proje... | 9 | const | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | participant_subscriptions | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | participant_subscription_project.part... | 1 | 10.00 | Using where |
| 4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | participant_subscription_project | NULL | ref | participant_subscription_project_unique,participan... | participant_subscription_project_project_id_foreig... | 8 | const | 3 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | participant_subscriptions | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | participant_subscription_project.part... | 1 | 10.00 | Using where |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | participant_subscriptions | NULL | ref | participant_subscriptions_alternative_project_id_f... | participant_subscriptions_alternative_project_id_f... | 9 | const | 1 | 10.00 | Using where |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | subscription_details | NULL | eq_ref | subscription_details_participant_subscription_id_u... | subscription_details_participant_subscription_id_u... | 9 | participant_subscriptions.id | 1 | 10.00 | Using where; Not exists |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | participant_subscriptions | NULL | ref | participant_subscriptions_project_id_foreign | participant_subscriptions_project_id_foreign | 9 | const | 1 | 10.00 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | subscription_details | NULL | eq_ref | subscription_details_participant_subscription_id_u... | subscription_details_participant_subscription_id_u... | 9 | participant_subscriptions.id | 1 | 10.00 | Using where; Not exists |

This query takes about 480 ms. As this query could also be used in a paginated result, I tried to make the query faster with the following result:

```sql
SELECT `projects`.*,
(
           SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `participant_subscriptions`
            LEFT JOIN `participant_subscription_project` ON `participant_subscription_project`.`participant_subscription_id` = `participant_subscriptions`.`id`
            LEFT JOIN `subscription_details` ON
               `subscription_details`.`participant_subscription_id` = `participant_subscriptions`.`id` OR
               `subscription_details`.`participant_subscription_project_id` = `participant_subscription_project`.`id`
           WHERE
               `participant_subscriptions`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
             AND COALESCE(
                 `participant_subscriptions`.`project_id`,
                 `participant_subscriptions`.`alternative_project_id`,
                 `participant_subscription_project`.`project_id`,
                 `participant_subscription_project`.`alternative_project_id`
             ) = `projects`.`id`
             AND NOT (`subscription_details`.`option` = 1 AND `subscription_details`.`confirmed` = 1)
       ) AS `participants_count`
FROM `projects` WHERE `projects`.`id` = 1
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | projects | NULL | const | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | const | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | participant_subscriptions | NULL | ALL | PRIMARY | NULL | NULL | NULL | 13416 | 10.00 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | participant_subscription_project | NULL | ref | participant_subscription_project_unique | participant_subscription_project_unique | 8 | participant_subscriptions.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | subscription_details | NULL | ALL | subscription_details_participant_subscription_id_u... | NULL | NULL | NULL | 25617 | 0.04 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0xA) |

However, this query is even slower taking at least 500ms. My question is, is it possible to make this sub-query faster.

Comment: Could you add the execution plan for your queries (e.g. the output of `explain select...`), as well as your tables as create statements (e.g. the output of `create table participant_subscription_project` and so on). It makes it easier to check indexes, datatypes, test something, ...  Also, your 2nd query is in most circumstances not equivalent to the first one (and cannot use indexes on the coalesce-columns). Also, what do you mean (in your title) with "half a second per row", if your complete query takes only half a second.

Comment: @Solarflare have added what you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These INDEXes might help

```
subscription_details:  (confirmed, option, participant_subscription_id)
participant_subscriptions:  INDEX(project_id, deleted_at, id)
participant_subscriptions:  INDEX(deleted_at, alternative_project_id, id)
participant_subscription_project:  INDEX(project_id, participant_subscription_id)
participant_subscription_project:  INDEX(alternative_project_id, participant_subscription_id)
```